# How to correctly import FormGroup in NgModule in Angular 2

Tags: angular, import, angular2-forms, ng-modules

I try to import `FromGroup`, `FormBuilder` and `FormControl` to my `CustomModule`:

```
import { FormsModule, FormGroup }   from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    FormGroup
  ]
})
```

But it throws an error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'FormGroup'
>   imported by the module 'CustomModule'

If i only import `FormsModule` it works fine though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't add `FormGroup` to module's imports, just import it in the component in which you want to use `FormGroup`. You can only add **MODULES** to module's `imports`. Also, if you want to use `FormGroup` directive, you will need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
```