# How to add debounce time to in input search box in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can i add debounce time to dynamic search box that searches data on table data ? I have looked at some solution on the site but my code is little bit different, I do not use any throttle or something else so I am just confused.

my template code:

```
<input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search element">
```

and typescript for that is:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.tableDataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

I want to add debounce time for that the search will be made every 2 seconds and not sending lots of request for every change.

Thanks in advance

I have tried to call the method from another method with pipe

```
filterData(filterValue: string) {
    this.applyFilter(filterValue).pipe(debounceTime(2000))
}
```

but now it says, *pipe does not exist on type void*

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41308826/1009922).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rxjs debounce on react text input component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299632/rxjs-debounce-on-react-text-input-component)

Comment: no they are not same i think.

Comment: No, they are completely the same.

Comment: i tried already like in the answers you suggested but pipe,subscribe,oberve does not exist on type void error comes. I tried as in the question update in last part.

Comment: Using a FormControl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732416/rxjs-distinctuntilchanged-with-keyup-event/50734973?noredirect=1#comment96296332_50734973

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using pipe operator against a string. You can only use pipe against an Observable. So, You should create a `Subject` in your component. `Subject` in RxJS acts as both an Observable and Observer. In other words, it emits the value as well as listen for that value when the value changes.

```
private searchSub$ = new Subject<string>();

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.searchSub$.next(filterValue)
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.searchSub$.pipe(
     debounceTime(400),
     distinctUntilChanged()
   ).subscribe((filterValue: string) => {
     this.tableDataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
   });
}
```

When the `applyFilter()` method calls on every key press, the Subject emits the filterValue. In your `ngOnInit()`, you should listen / subscribe to you Subject, so there you can use the `pipe` operator and `debounceTime`.

Comment: Thanks! nice way to go with.

Answer (score 11):

Template:

```html
<input matInput (input)="terms$.next($event.target.value)" type="text" 
  placeholder="Search element">
```

Component:

```js
private terms$ = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit () {
  this.terms$.pipe(
    debounceTime(400), // discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between output
    distinctUntilChanged() // only emit when value has changed
  ).subscribe(term => {
    // do your search with the term
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [lodash-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-decorators) and lodash

```
import { Debounce } from 'lodash-decorators';

class AnyClass {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  @Debounce(100)
  filterData(filterValue: string) {
    ...
  }
}
```